# Creating Dummy Records in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to create empty record with value from previous record for a given date range.
For example, suppose I have table having following columns - Data and Balance with data as follows -

```
05/05/2015 - 500
09/05/2015 - 700
```

Now, I want to display the records for date 01/05/2015 to 10/05/2015 as follows

```
01/05/2015 - 0
02/05/2015 - 0
03/05/2015 - 0
04/05/2015 - 0
05/05/2015 - 500
06/05/2015 - 500
07/05/2015 - 500
08/05/2015 - 500
09/05/2015 - 700
10/05/2015 - 700
```

Is there any analytical function in oracle or any tricks to calculate that type of record set?
Please suggest.

Comment: what is your thinking behind what row gets 0/500/700

Comment: See this [ROW GENERATOR method](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/tag/row-generator/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use hierarchical query to generate the data range and then OUTER JOIN with your table.
Then use SUM analytical function to get the latest value for each date.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3487f/5)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table myt(
  date_ date,
  balance_ number
  );

 insert into myt values(date'2015-05-05',500);
 insert into myt values(date'2015-05-09',700);
```

**Query 1**:

```
with date_list(dates_) as (
  select date'2015-05-01' + level - 1
  from dual
  connect by date'2015-05-01' + level - 1 <= date'2015-05-10'
)
select date_list.dates_, myt.balance_, 
coalesce(last_value(myt.balance_) ignore nulls over (order by date_list.dates_),0) balance2,
sum(coalesce(myt.balance_,0)) over (order by date_list.dates_) balance3
from date_list left outer join myt
on date_list.dates_ = myt.date_
order by date_list.dates_
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3487f/5/0)**:

```
|                DATES_ | BALANCE_ | BALANCE2 | BALANCE3 |
|-----------------------|----------|----------|----------|
| May, 01 2015 00:00:00 |   (null) |        0 |        0 |
| May, 02 2015 00:00:00 |   (null) |        0 |        0 |
| May, 03 2015 00:00:00 |   (null) |        0 |        0 |
| May, 04 2015 00:00:00 |   (null) |        0 |        0 |
| May, 05 2015 00:00:00 |      500 |      500 |      500 |
| May, 06 2015 00:00:00 |   (null) |      500 |      500 |
| May, 07 2015 00:00:00 |   (null) |      500 |      500 |
| May, 08 2015 00:00:00 |   (null) |      500 |      500 |
| May, 09 2015 00:00:00 |      700 |      700 |     1200 |
| May, 10 2015 00:00:00 |   (null) |      700 |     1200 |
```